# Reading a Text File and storing the data in Private member variables of a Class - C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, file-handling

I have a `myFile.txt` file and it contains the First Name, Last Name and an ID of a student in the following format,

`First-Name  Last-Name   ID` **<-- This line isn't included in the file**

`Steve        Smith    12345` **<-- This line is included in the file**

I also have a class `Student` that looks like

```
class Student
{
private:
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
    int id;
public:
    Student();
    Student(std::string fname, std::string lname, int i);
    ~Student();

    void setFirstName(std::string fnam);
    std::string getFirstName();

    void setLastName(std::string lnam);
    std::string getLastName();

    void SetID(int i);
    int getID();
};
```

I want to read the `myFile.txt` file and store the information in the respective **private member variables**  of the student class.

I know i have to overload the `>>` operator but i can't figure out how to store the data from the file in to respective variables when the variables are **private**.

To write in to the file, i overloaded the `<<` operator as follows.

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, Student &stu)
{
    out << stu.getFirstName() << " " << stu.getLastName() << " " << stu.getID() << std::endl;
    return out;
}
```

**Question:** How do i overload the `>>` operator so that data from the text file is stored in the respective variables  when the variables are **private** and can only be accessed using `setter` and `getter` functions ?

```
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream &in, Student &stu)
{

    in >> //what do i write here ? do i have to call the setter functions ? if so, how ?
    return in;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would read something like that from plain old `std::cin`, how would you do then?

It's the same for your input operator. Read into three different variables, and call the setter functions with them.

You can also make the input operator a `friend` of the class, and then you can input directly into the private variables. For input and output operators it's very common to make them friend functions.